# Pandas multiple find strings

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, series

I'm working on a script to read and process data from Excel files and I need to filter rows containing several strings.

Currently, the filter method is hard coded for every type of Excel sheet (Each sheet type gets one child class that inherits from a parent that deals with reading the file and first processing) that I'm reading, but as this gets very tedious as the number of sheets I have to analyze is growing, I am looking for a more elegant solution.

Right now, I have implemented it like this:

```
def _find(self,find_str,column='Data1'):
    return (self.df[column].str.find(find_str) > -1)
def filter(self):
    self.df_filter = self.df[(self._find('This') | self._find('is')) 
                           & self._find('an') | self._find('example')]
```

with a reimplemented filter method for every child class. Occasionally the logical (actually binary) expressions can get very long.

Is there a consistent, readable way to shorten this?
I thought of something along the lines of passing a logical expression-like object to a generalized filter function, like

```
gen_find(('This' | 'is') & 'an' | 'example')
```

(I know this excactly would probably be a bad idea, but you get the point)

Answer (score 0):

`pd.Series.str.find(x) > -1` is equivalent to `pd.Series.str.contains(x)`. Both give Boolean series which you can use for filtering your dataframe. One way to simplify your logic is to use regex with `pd.Series.str.contains`.

For example, define a list of substrings you wish to find:

```
L = ['This', 'is', 'an', 'example']
```

Then combine them in a regex expression. If you have characters that need escaping, then use `re.escape`:

```
import re
regexp = '|'.join([re.escape(i) for i in L])
```

Finally, incorporate this expression in your series mask:

```
df = df[df['col'].str.contains(regexp)]
```

You can combine multiple `or` conditions with the `&` operator:

```
mask1 = df['col'].str.contains(regexp1)
mask2 = df['col'].str.contains(regexp2)

df = df[mask1 & mask2]
```

Comment: Thank you, this shortened my code somewhat, but doesn't really get rid of the need for defining the filter method in each child class.

Comment: Sure, hopefully someone has a better solution. Keep this question open. Maybe there's a smart intersection of or_conditions regex method.